# AngularJS module not defined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I just got a book called "Pro Angular" from Apress by Adam Freeman. I have never used Angular JS before and I am not really sure why this isn't working but I'll explain where I am currently. Ok, so the first project I am currently doing is a basic to do list using Angular to bind certain data to html tags using data-binding and I've just added a line defining a module. Problem is my environment is claiming that the module is not being defined. I'm not sure what it is talking about. Here is my source so far.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
<head>
    <title>TO DO List</title>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script>

        var model = {
            user: "Adam",
            items: [{ action: "Buy Flowers", done: false },
                        { action: "Get Shoes", done: false },
                        { action: "Collect Tickets", done: true },
                        { action: "Call Joe", done: false }]
        };

        var todoApp = angular.module("todoApp", []);

        todoApp.controller("ToDoCtrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.todo = model;
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ToDoCtrl">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>
            {{todo.user}}'s To Do List
            <span class="label label-default">{{todo.items.length}}</span>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Done</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in todo.items">
                    <td>{{item.action}}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.done" /></td>                    
                    <td>{{item.done}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

The line it is talking about is Ln-18. Any help with an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `angular.js` the right path to the angularjs file,

Comment: @PatrickEvans That would give `angular is not defined` error

Comment: @sohaiby I do believe I have the correct file location, here is my directory with files. http://vvcap.net/db/ZeA9gMkewihJxEBVRhQV.htp

Comment: What is the actual text of the error you are getting?

Comment: @jme11 I switched out my Angular JS file and the Bootstrap file with what you use and that worked.

Comment: @ patrick evans Here is exactly what I'm seeing. https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0ydrchnzx5kbn1/Screenshot%202015-05-10%2002.38.20.png?dl=0

Comment: I figured out it is my environment setup. I will have to figure out what changed between different runs.